# Foundation 5 off-canvas menu minimum code?

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation-5

I would like to avoid adding the entire Foundation library to my site in order to get one single feature -- the off-canvas menu. Does anyone know how to get just necessary js and css required to deliver the menu functionality?

Comment: You could download your custom build, just toggle the components you need [Custom Foundation Download](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation)

Comment: Thanks. That is what I did. Seems like there is still a lot of extra overhead in the foundation js and css files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can! I use a default foundation_settings.sass file ([github repo](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/_settings.scss)) in which I override the styles if needed, and on the bottom of it instead of including the whole foundation, I include individual modules.

Maybe you have an app.sass file where you import foundation, but it's the same principle either way.

For example:

```
// @import 'foundation'; <-- nope
@import "foundation/components/global";
@import "foundation/components/grid";
// @import "foundation/components/visibility";
@import "foundation/components/block-grid";
// @import "foundation/components/type";
// @import "foundation/components/buttons";
@import "foundation/components/forms";
// @import "foundation/components/custom-forms";
// @import "foundation/components/button-groups";
// @import "foundation/components/dropdown-buttons"
...
```

You can also read about it in Foundatoin docs [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/using-sass.html).